# "Run as; Android Application" doesn't work on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, device

I'm new to android development, but I've been following the Google's tutorials on building an application. Unfortunately, I get stuck on "Running on a Real Device" because whenever I click Run as; Android Application nothing happens on my phone.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Also:

- My phone's a Motorola Razr M, running 4.1.2
- USB debugging is enabled, unknown sources enabled.
- Latest USB drivers are installed
- My eclipse is part of the ADT bundle from Google.

Comment: Are you sure that the computer is recognizing the phone? Try ADB device, it should return the device you have connected. Often times, the computer isn't recognizing the device, even though it's plugged in.

Comment: @Blaine Thanks for the reply, but I don't know how to try ADB device :'(. When I click Window >> Show View >> Other >> Android/Devices, it shows my phone: [link](http://i.imgur.com/NvlNWoZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to try here (assuming your project has no errors):
Click on the arrow on the run button and then specifically select your project to run.
[image: How to run project]

Check if you are able to run your project in an emulator also -- see screenshot below.
[image: Run in emulator]

Below is how you check if your phone is recognized by Eclipse - if it is ... you will most definitely see a lot of output in LogCat. if your phone is successfully connected, you will see lots of messages scrolling in the logCat.
[image]